# Why are my css/font icons displaying as codes?

Tags: css, icons

I am using the Gumby responsive framework for a website I am building and since I downloaded the zip and uploaded it the icons haven't worked.

http://www.petsintransit.co.uk/ui.htm

If you look towards the bottom of the page above you will see that the Icons are displaying as below:

\2712
\2699

**My question is: How do I get the icons to display correctly?**

The page has UTF-8 and the fonts are uploaded into the fonts/icons folder...

I look forward to hearing from you.

Shaun

Comment: the link doesn't work

Comment: http://www.petsintransit.co.uk/ui